# Rails Active Record how to check associated record not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't find query interface from Active Record to show only ***categories*** that have at least one ***product***. how to do that?

***category.rb***

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

***product.rb***

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

thank you

Comment: `@category = Category.first @category.products.empty?` this way using `empty?`

Comment: got this error sir: undefined method `products' for nil:NilClass

Comment: you do not have any `category` in `categories` table

Answer (score 1):

```
@categories = Category.joins(:products).where('products.id is not null').group('products.category_id')
```

it will show only category that have at least one product.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
@categories = Category.joins(:products).where('categories.id is not null').group('products.id')
```